# How to sync archived Sitecore items in Visual Studio Solution using TDS Sync

Tags: tds

I have archived some items in the `Core DB` of Sitecore. I am able to view these items

[image]

But, how do sync them in the `TDS` project in `Visual Studio Solution`, because `Get Sitecore Items or Sync With Sitecore` option only shows items that are in the content tree, but these archived items are not in the content tree.

Comment: I think the question is, why did you archive these items in the core database?

Comment: @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain  This is related to some optimization in Experience Editor